# Android: Using selector to set background color for image view

Tags: android, colors, background, css-selectors, android-imageview

I am trying to set the background color of an image view.

```
 <ImageView 
     android:id="@+id/my_image"
     android:src="@drawable/my_icon"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
     android:layout_weight="1"  
     android:clickable="true" 
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:background="@drawable/selector_image_view" />
```

I am using the following selector.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">     
 <item android:state_selected="true" android:background="@color/Violet" />    
 <item android:state_pressed="true" android:background="@color/red" />
 <item android:background="@color/white" />
 </selector>
```

But, it crashes if I try to use the selector with a runtime exception. What am I doing wrong?

**My logcat**

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.X.XCamera/com.X.XCamera.XCameraActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class <unknown>
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class <unknown>
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at com.X.XCamera.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:52)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at com.X.XCamera.XCameraActivity.onCreate(XCameraActivity.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    ... 11 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:108)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    ... 22 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/selector_image_view.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02000e
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1697)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2045)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:112)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    ... 26 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #3: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:167)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4196):    ... 29 more
W/ActivityManager( 1707):   Force finishing activity com.X.XCamera/.XCameraActivity
I/IMGSRV  ( 1707): gralloc.c:803: gralloc_device_alloc: Allocated a new surface:
I/IMGSRV  ( 1707):        width -> 800
I/IMGSRV  ( 1707):       height -> 382
I/IMGSRV  ( 1707):       format -> 1 (HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBA_8888)
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your Logcat:

> E/AndroidRuntime( 4196): Caused by:
>   org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #3: tag
>   requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable

LogCat is pointing out that your `<item>` tag should include `android:drawable` tag.

You selector file should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">     
     <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/Violet" />    
     <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/red" />
     <item android:drawable="@color/white" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 18):

The simplest way to do what you want is adding a child node to the item instead of using its `drawable` attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <color android:color="@color/Violet" />
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <color android:color="@color/red" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <color android:color="@color/white" />
    </item>
</selector>
```

Here you can use direct values for color as well (e.g. #FFFF0000 instead of "@color/red") to save yourself from defining many color resources.

Answer (score 14):

You cannot use background tag in selector file.Instead,you can use it like:

**1.** Create a color.xml in "values" folder under "res" folder:

**color.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <drawable name="color_one">#110000</drawable>
    <drawable name="color_two">#001111</drawable>
    <drawable name="color_three">#001100</drawable>    
</resources>
```

**2.** Now,Use this file in your selector file like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">     
     <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/color_one" />    
     <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/color_two" />
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/color_three"/>
 </selector>
```

Comment: Should that not be <color > instead of <drawable >? I am not sure of th answer, so I phrase that as a question rather than a correction. If you could clarify, I would be grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/black_mediam" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/black_mediam" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/menu_bg" />
</selector>
```

it is working for ImageView and Button

```
      <Button
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/image_selecter"
            android:id="@+id/btn_delete_gif"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:text="Yes"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_width="175dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


     <ImageView
            android:padding="@dimen/_3sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/image_selecter"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:id="@+id/delete_gif_giflistview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_gif"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp" />
```