# Android spinner behavior

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, spinner

I overwrite the behavior of a spinner, to add odd and even colors to the drop down list, in this way.

```
    SimpleCursorAdapter productsListAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MyActivity.this, R.layout.spinner_drop_down_products, cursor, column, viewIds) {
    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
        if (position % 2 == 0) { 
            view.setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.rgb(214, 214, 214));
        }
        return view;
    }
};
```

The dropdown rows look as i expected ... but i loose the highlight on pressing each row.
What i forget to add to the code?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually android framework uses selectors for all states like:

1. `normal enabled`
2. `pressed`
3. `highlight`
4. `focused`

The default selector for list is `list_selector_background.xml` You can [see here](http://code.google.com/p/nookdevs/source/browse/trunk/nookLibrary/res/drawable/list_selector_background.xml?r=29).

You have to provide [this by yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8800598/593709). Say you have made a `you_own_selector.xml` 
then you will give this as a background of your View like this:

```
view.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.you_own_selector);
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3565624/593709) is another nice post about using selectors in android.