# Change border of Edittext onFouce (Android)

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am making an app in android.

There are 3 edittext in one page. I just want to change border color of edit text while in am writing on them . In simple words. Change border color on four.

Right now using this code for background and border color

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#FF0000" />
</shape>
```

But want to change onFocus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your main_activity.xml, in the outermost wrapper say its a linear layout, write these 2 lines:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
```

and then in the already existing file write ->

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_focused="true"

    >
    <shape >
        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
<stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#FF0000" />

    </shape>


</item>

<item android:state_window_focused="false">
    //the code for the edittext which will be by default

</item>

</selector>
```

Comment: Can you mention where to add these two lines given in your comment ?    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"

Comment: Yes in your activity_main.xml in the layout folder. Remember to put it in the outermost wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Make another shape in xml with the color you want to change while typing on it. And with a selector you can change it onfocus.

try it . i think its helpfull.

[Android: Using selector to set background color for image view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800343/android-using-selector-to-set-background-color-for-image-view)

this link will help you on  using seletors.