# How to save imagebutton's state when pressed?

Tags: java, android

I created an image button that will change to another image when pressed. But, when I pressed the back button or switch to `landscape` orientation, the image button will go back to its default image.

**I reckon that i need to save the image's state when it is pressed?**

Anyone can help?

```
ib1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(isPressed)
            ib1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star_pressed);

        else
            ib1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star_unpressed);
            isPressed = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: You can save the state to SharedPreferences, then on the onResume method, you can load in the state and set the background

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Using selector to set background color for image view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800343/android-using-selector-to-set-background-color-for-image-view)

Comment: To preserve the state, it would be better to use the solution suggested by @Thomas. The "isPressed" flag could be used to decide the state in "onResume", and a background image be set accordingly

Answer (score 0):

**Do this for orientation changes**

```
  <activity android:name=".Youractivity"

        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    >

    </activity>
```

Comment: For your backbutton... what you do please post code... on backpressed what you do

Answer (score 0):

Add bellow code in your manifest file

```
<activity
      android:name="YourActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" //if you need
      android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" //if you need
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put button state in `sharedpreferences` and get button state in `onResume` method of activity.